# Product show all on listing page. how to fix it

Tags: magento-1.9

I got strange problem. i have install magento 1.9 with sample data and using RWD / Base / our responsive theme without any custom.

I have set admin catalog to show 5,10,15,20. but on listing page alway show all product at one page:

http://dcctoyou.com/dev2/men/new-arrivals.html

How can I fix this issue ?

Note:
I install Lazyload from mgt but I disabled it still show all products.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any other extension that hooks into the product collection and calls load or iterates through it before the limits are set?

Comment: I hav tried disabled all installed module. it still show all products. could you check admin for me ?

Comment: @Ryo in what way did you disable modules?

Comment: I disabled through admin advance. I think I found problem. my template overwrite catalog page. but after I disable this module page navigator is just disappear.

Comment: Disabling module output in admin panel only hides the blocks of the module but does not disable its functionality. Sounds like the problem comes from your custom theme and cannot be reproduced with the default rwd theme? In this case, please show relevant code, or the question is likely to be closed as not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

$collection = Mage::getModel('...')
            ->getCollection()
            ->setPageSize(5)
            ->setCurPage(1);

You may try this code